# How to keep strings with "/" and "-" separate when using split(""\\W+)

Tags: java, split, punctuation

I have read a txt document to pass individual words through a profanity filter, I used a split to remove punction but for two words separated with "-" or "/" they become one. eg "easy/hard" would become "easyhard". How can I keep it two separate strings?

```
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (scan2.hasNextLine()){
            Scanner scan3 = new Scanner (scan2.nextLine());
            while (scan3.hasNext()){
                String word = scan3.next();
                String[] refinedWord = word.split("\\W+");
```

Comment: What is the value of `word`? What is the value of `refinedWord `?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all non alphabetic character with a single space before running your split.

word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opposite using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and then exclude matching `-` and `/`

```
word.split("[^\\w/-]+");
```